# How to deal with .gz input files with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, zip, gzip, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

Please allow me to provide a scenario:

`hadoop jar test.jar Test inputFileFolder outputFileFolder`

where

- `test.jar` sorts info by key, time, and place
- `inputFileFolder` contains multiple .gz files, each .gz file is about 10GB
- `outputFileFolder` contains bunch of .gz files

My question is which is the best way to deal with those .gz file in the inputFileFolder? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop will automatically detect and read .gz files. However as .gz is not a splittable compression format, each file will be read by a single mapper. Your best bet is to use another format such as Snappy, or to decompress, split and re-compress into smaller, block-sized files.